# How do I check if a lightswitch field is false?

Tags: lightswitch

I have a Resources page and an archived Resources page made up of entries. I want to show all current resources on the main page (this list should not include the archived ones) and on the archived page I only want to show only archived resources. I am using a lightswitch field to toggle whether a resource is archived or not.

The archived-only page works as expected, it shows only the archived resources, using this:

```
{% set resources = craft.entries.relatedTo({ targetElement: category }).order('title').archivedResource('1') %}
```

The main page, which should show all resource entries except archived ones actually shows all resources (archived and unarchived). I’m using this code:

```
{% set resources = craft.entries.relatedTo({ targetElement: category }).order('title').archivedResource('0') %}
```

It appears that the `.archivedResource(‘0’)` bit is not having any affect. Should I be using some other method to check whether a switch field is toggled or not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `'not 1'` instead of `'0'`:

```
{% set resources = craft.entries.relatedTo({ targetElement: category }).order('title').archivedResource('not 1') %}
```