# getCriteria not working as expected with boolean field types

Tags: plugin-development, database, elementcriteriamodel, elementtype

I have a custom content table for an elementType. I have a few fields set up in my `Record` as boolean. The two fields are `approved` and `denied` I have to search the database where both fields are set to zero/false.

I can only get the values to show up in `$query->params` inside my `modifyElementsQuery()` method when I set `$criteria->approved/denied` to (string)"1". Setting these to true, false, or (string)"0" cause them to not show up in the `$query->params` list.

How do I work with a boolean field in this manner? I need `Where denied = '0'` to show up in the query when i set `$criteria->denied = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work (not tested):

```
$criteria->setAttribute('denied', 'not 1');
```

As when [using the `ElementCriteriaModel` in Twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-do-i-check-if-a-lightswitch-field-is-false/239#239), you can't directly check for "falsey" values.

Comment: Yes this is the correct way to test for a false boolean in the database! Thanks!

Comment: I actually ended up using `$criteria->denied = 'not 1';`

Comment: Sure, that's an alternative. It's just calling the `setAttribute` method behind the scenes anyway.